# EditText customization in an alertdialog

Tags: android

I have an AlertDialog and I put EditText in it but i want my EditText to accept only the following input:
`(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.,,)`

How can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Treatment.this);
alert.setTitle("Weigthed Mean!");
alert.setIcon(R.drawable.droid);

Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
final TextView sum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fakeDB);
sum.setText(b.getCharSequence("input"));

final EditText x = new EditText (Treatment.this);
final EditText y = new EditText (Treatment.this);

x.setText(sum.getText().toString());
y.setHint("Enter the weights to the x values");

LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(Treatment.this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

ll.addView(x);
ll.addView(y);
alert.setView(ll);

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                
        alert.setOnCancelListener(null);
    }
});

alert.create();
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final EditText x = new EditText (Treatment.this);
final EditText y = new EditText (Treatment.this);

x.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789.,"));
y.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789.,"));
```

Answer (score 3):

to set the `EditText` type progromatically try:

```
x.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

you can use class with a flag to create decimal like:

```
x.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

but it wont add ',' to it however what @CodeMonkey is correct

check [Input Types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) for more information about types of flags and classes

Answer (score 2):

@Osama is on the right track here, and you can read more about changing the type of keyboard [here](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/index.html). It is also possible to specify which characters you would like to have appear in your `EditText` by setting a `KeyListener`:

```
x.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
x.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789.,"));
```

or something similar.